# How to enable and disable an object when something happens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The player changes its color after passing through every wall. If the player is Yellow and the wall is Red then, the color of the player becomes orange. Also the next wall will be spawned with a little orange part. However, I could not turn on and off the orange wall object. The code below changes the players color and also changes the wall's color. However I could not make it acitve the wall (Which is deployBlack) and after passing through it deactivating it. Here is my code :

```
if(col.tag!= currentColor){
        if (currentColor=="Yellow" && col.tag=="Red"){
            sr.color=colorOrange;
            currentColor="Orange";
            deployBlack.SetActive(true);
            whitesr.color=colorOrange; 
            deployBlack.SetActive(false);
      }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you declare and initialize deployBlack? Also, does an error pop when you try to set it to false? And lastly, throw a debug.log in between the last and second to last line in that checks to see if deployBlack is null.

Comment: I did not get an error pop up.

Comment: public GameObject deployBlack; I initialize it like that

Comment: Understood. You need to provide more code in order for me to understand this further. I don't know what happens to deployBlack after it get's set to false. Also please place the debug.log that I suggested. You need to find out if your IF statement is even executing after it turns the deployBlack to false.

Comment: I added my whole code

Answer (score 1):

Okay got it. Now that I see the rest of your code it's a lot easier to diagnose the problem. One of your `if` statements that occur `OnTriggerEnter2D` will eventually execute and when it does, it sets `deployBlack` to `true` but then immediately after that true statement it sets it to `false` every single time. Therefore you will see it until you pass through the wall one time. Once you do, it will end any `if` statement with the `deployBlack` set to `false`. This means that no matter what color anything is, the end result of the `deployBlack` will be `false`. You need to place the `deployBlack.SetActive(false);` somewhere else in your code.

I'm still a bit unsure as to what you are trying to achieve because I don't know how you are spawning walls, or what variable/sprite is the player, but regardless, your core issue is the fact that every `if` statement ends with `deployBlack.SetActive(false);` so it will always appear as false except for the couple of milliseconds that it is set to `true`.

Hope this helps!